# Как в блочной верстке boostrap сделать, чтобы блок не двигался?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
.avatar {
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 240px;
}
.wall {
    background-color: #a9a9a9;
    height: 290px;
}
.frends {
    background-color: #cacaca;
    height: 240px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.row {
    clear:both; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="avatar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="wall"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="frends"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

При увеличении высоты блока `wall` блок `frends` сдвигается вниз, как мне оставить четко под блоком `avatar`? (перефразирую, мне нужно чтобы при увеличении высоты блока `wall`, блок `frends` был под блоком `avatar`.)

**Дополнение из комментариев к ответам**

Мне нужно чтобы `frends` был прижат к avatar. Под `frends` будет еще один такой же блок, и он должен быть прижат к `frends`. А `wall` будет автоматически менять высоту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не проверял, но как-то так

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 avatar"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 frends"></div>
     <div class="col-sm-12 another one"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 wall"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по твоему вопросу. ты уже неправильную верстку задал. у тебя идет 2 блока row которые по любому двигаться будут. Попробуй абсолютное позиционирование сделать для блока friend и перенеси его внутрь первого row

Comment: а без абсолютного позиционирования? 
мне нужно 3 одинаковых блока как у аватар друг под другом слева, и блок с авт. высотой wall справа

Comment: Можешь загрузить куда нибудь , что бы визуально посмотреть , так гораздо проще будет :)

Comment: нажми кнопку выполнить код, я поставил у блока wall большую высоту чтобы было заметно

Answer (score 0):

Почему тогда сразу не сделать как надо?
Верстка:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="avatar"></div>
   <div class="frends"></div>
   <div class="something"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="wall"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
.avatar { background-color: #cacaca; height: 240px; }
.wall { background-color: #a9a9a9; height: 290px; margin-top:1em;}
.frends { background-color: #cacaca; height: 240px; }
.something { background-color: #ccc; height: 100px; }
.avatar, . something, .friends, .wall { clear:both; }
```

Comment: тоже самое, блок сдвигается

Comment: можно скриншот проблемы, а то не понятно, что вам нужно

Comment: нажми кнопку выполнить код, я поставил у блока wall большую высоту чтобы было заметно

Comment: т.е. вам надо, чтобы когда увеличивался wall, friends был прижат к avatar?

Comment: Да, мне нужно чтобы frends был прижат к avatar, под frends будет еще один такой же блок, и он должен быть прижат к frends, а wall будет автоматически менять высоту

Comment: @Ne0lite Это - рабочее решение (по крайней мере, в редакции на 19:56 по Москве). А если убрать `.avatar, . something, .friends, .wall { clear:both; }` и `margin-top:1em;`, то получится лаконично и (имхо) лучше, чем у toxxxa.